# Domain and limit of vectors

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Let $r(t) = \langle(\sqrt{2-t}),(((e^t)-1)/t),\ln(t+1)\rangle$

a) Find the domain of $r(t)$

(I guessed the domain is (0,2) because I figured $2-t \geq 0,t \geq 0, and t> -1.$ But i am not sure)

b) Find the limit $r(t)$ as $t$ goes to 0

(I worked out $\lim r(t) = \langle \sqrt{ 2},1,0 \rangle$ (since all the limit's exist))

Answer (score 0):

You got (b) right, but you missed something in (a). You need $t \neq 0$ since you have $t$ in the denominator in the second coordinate. Therefore $t \in (-1, 2] - {0}$.